# Nested elements naming style (Jade, HAML, Slim)

Tags: css, haml, pug, slim, smacss

Looking for solution how to use SMACSS naming convention with jade, haml or slim template engine.

Expect following jade code :

```
.module
  .child
  .child
```

as output i'll get following:

```
<div class="module">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

but i'd like to reach following result:

```
<div class="module">
  <div class="module-child"></div>
  <div class="module-child"></div>
</div>
```

is there any solution to manage it like i can do it in SASS for example, i mean avoid adding 'module-' string to each 'child' manually ?

**UPDATE**

Also acceptable solutions with Haml and Slim

Comment: I use variables for BEM classnames.

Comment: @Grawl, thanks for response, could you please addsomeexamples?

Comment: module-child is a new class i suppose right ? not module class ( multi class i mean )

Comment: @ProllyGeek, exactly, the goal is create new class name with parent name as prefix

Comment: @Evgeniy I was mean exactly what Rwam Dev wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the closest I got with **jade** ([live playground here](http://jade-lang.com)):

```
mixin e(elt)
  - var a = attributes;
  - var cl = attributes.class;delete attributes.class
  - var elt = elt ? elt : 'div' // If no parameter given
  if cl
    - var cl = parent + '-' + cl
  else
    - var cl = parent
  #{elt}&attributes({'class': cl}, attributes)
    block

- var parent = 'box'
+e('aside')#so-special
  +e('h2').title Related
  +e('ul').list
    +e('li').item: +e('a')(href='#').link Item 1
    +e('li').item: +e('span').link.current Item 2 and current
    +e('li').item#third(data-dash='fine', aria-live='polite') Item 3 not even a link
      | multi-line
      | block
    // - var parent = 'other' problem of scope I guess 
    +e('li').item lorem ipsum dolor sit amet

- var parent = 'footer'
+e('footer')(role='contentInfo')
  +e.inner © Company - 2014
```

A mixin named `e` will output an element taken as a parameter (default is `div`) with its attributes and content as is, except for the first class that'll be prefixed with the value of the variable `parent` (or will be the value of `parent` itself if it hasn't any class)
I prefer using default jade syntax for attributes, including class and id than passing many parameters to a mixin (this one doesn't need any if it's a div, as with `.sth text`'d output `<div class="sth>text</div>` and `+e.sth text` will output `<div class="parent-sth>text</div>`)
Mixin would be shorter if it didn't have to deal with other attributes (href, id, data-*, role, etc)
Remaining problem: changing the value of `parent` has no effect when it's indented. It had with simpler previous attempts so I guess it's related to scope of variables. You theoretically don't want to change the prefix for child elements but in practice... Maybe as a second optional parameter?

Things I had problem with while playing with jade:

- attributes doesn't work as expected. Now it's `&attributes(attributes)`. Thanks to [jade-book issue on GitHub](https://github.com/slang800/jade-book/issues/16)
- but it'll output class untouched plus the prefixed one, so I had to remove it (`delete`) in a place it'd be executed by jade

Comment: looks like using mixin is the best solution. It more scalable, has less boilerplate code and has more readable syntax

Comment: Looks good but unclear to read. I think that abbreviating everything is a big evil. Here's my clear view: http://codepen.io/Grawl/pen/eyDau

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts from me: what's wrong with a variable?

```
- var myModule = 'module'
div(class="#{myModule}")
  div(class="#{myModule}-child")
  div(class="#{myModule}-child")
```

or combine it with an each:

```
- var myModule2 = 'foobar'
div(class="#{myModule2}")
  each idx in [0, 1, 2, 3]
    div(class="#{myModule2}-child") I'm child #{idx}
```

Sure, there is much more code to write, but if a change is neccessary then you must do this only at one point.

Ciao
Ralf

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, yep, it possible to use vars, but i'm looking for most lightweight approach. (like in sass for eg). Maybe there is any ways to reach the goal updating core configs

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this with SASS. As long as you have the latest SASS version, you should be able to use the following syntax:

```
.module {
    &-child {

    }
}
```

Have a look at this article for more information on newer features of SASS http://davidwalsh.name/future-sass

Comment: thx for responce, yep, its clear with sass, i have an issue with generating html with same class names with jade :)

Comment: Ahh yep, should have seen that, sorry haha.
Well I don't know Jade as well as I know SASS, but from my knowledge I don't think that it's possible. In saying that though, I could be dead wrong.